# Overlapping Community Detection with Netwrokx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to run overall ping community detection with networkx ([link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kclique.k_clique_communities.html))

networkx version is 2.1:

```
import networkx as nx
...
c = list(nx.k_clique_communities(G, 4))
```

however I got the error: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'k_clique_communities'. Not sure why the attribute does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Becasue it is not accessible the way you are doing it.

Looking at the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kclique.k_clique_communities.html?highlight=k_clique_communities#networkx.algorithms.community.kclique.k_clique_communities) you either have to write it as

`nw.algorithms.community.k_clique_communities(G, 4))`

or you import that specifically as described in the example in the documentation:

```
from networkx.algorithms.community import k_clique_communities
```